# .htaccess rewrite rule to external domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to set up a rewrite rule in `.htaccess` which will redirect http://website.com/blog to http://blog.website.com/, as well as routing any of the path parts to that request (i.e. http://website.com/blog/blog-post-1 -> http://blog.website.com/blog-post-1)

However, when I set up a rewrite rule like

`RewriteRule ^blog(.*)$ http://blog.website.com$1 [NC,L]`

The user is redirected to http://blog.website.com instead of seeing the request fulfilled on http://website.com/blog

Is it possible to do this without the user seeing a URL change? The reason for needing this is that we'd like to host the blog on a shared FTP server while keeping the main site on our AWS cloud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html) and the `ProxyPass` directive instead.

Something like:

```
ProxyPass /blog http://blog.website.com
ProxyPassReverse /blog http://blog.website.com
```

Comment: thanks! took me a bit to figure out this doesn't go in .htaccess, but helpful nonetheless